# Waiting for another thread to complete during dll unloading

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, mfc

I have an COM/ATL dll that initializes my custom logger in [DllGetClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910634.aspx) entry point and uninitializes this logger in overriden [ExitInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4zc2h84.aspx) function. Logger is implemented as seperate thread that periodically checks its buffer and quickly logs all records.

Now, the problem. As you know, Windows periodically checks for unused COM dlls and unloads them. I want to wait for logger thread to finish during dll unloading process, but I can't figure out the right way to do so. I have tried several solutions:

1. Wait for logger thread to complete using [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202783.aspx). This will not work because main thread is inside [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx) function.
2. Create custom event and fire it right before logger thread exits:

   ```
   SetEvent(_loggerExitEvent);
   // can be blocked here!
   return 0;
   ```

   This will not work either because this code block is not atomic. Logger thread can fire event and be blocked until dll is unloaded from memory and then wake up again only to produce nasty access violation error.
3. Use [TeminateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717.aspx) after receiving event described above if I'm 100% sure that logger thread will just return. This is very wonky.
4. Loop my main thread to periodically check logger thread status:

   ```
   while(TRUE == ::GetExitCodeThread(_loggerThread, &loggerThreadExitCode) && loggerThreadExitCode== STILL_ACTIVE)
   {
       Sleep(100);
   }
   ```

   Very dirty and wonky too. What if [GetExitCodeThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683190.aspx) returns FALSE?

So, the question is, **it there a right way to wait for another a thread to complete during dll unloading process**? Or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: "Windows periodically checks for unused dlls and unloads them": That's not true. That may happen with COM servers or the like, but not with ordinary DLLs. They will be in memory as long as your program does not call `FreeLibrary()`. If your DLL is indeed a COM library, then there are mechanism to avoid it being unloaded in the first place.

Comment: @rodrigo. Thanks for your correction. I forgot to mention that my dll is indeed a COM dll. I will update my question correspondingly. As for avoiding unloading, that is unfortunately not a solution in my case

Comment: Why can't you stop the thread in `ExitInstance()`? Do you want to keep it around for a while, just in case?